# EF4/Linq Eager Loading with Include fails to populate all results

Tags: linq-to-entities, include, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I'm trying out EF4 as part of a .Net 4.0 WCF service.  The aim of the service is to return document data as an array of entity objects to any of our ASP.Net apps.  The apps are still in .Net 2.0.  Due to the nature of the solution I've disabled LazyLoading at context level.  I started with this:

```
var revQuery = from revs in context.tbl_Document_Revision
                       where (revs.ID == myIDVar)
                       select revs;
```

Everything works ok, I receive the correct number of populated objects.  However when I add an Include into my query to allow us to pickup fields from a related table that has a defined navigation only the first record is returned fully populated to a calling application:

```
var revQuery = from revs in context.tbl_Document_Revision.Include("tbl_Staff")
                       where (revs.ID == myIDVar)
                       select revs;
```

The array is the correct size but all elements after the first are blank, default placeholders.  Its like using the Include has reverted to LazyLoading and I can't seem to kick it into line.  Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Can you post the fragment of your EDMX diagram that shows the DocRevision and StaffNames entities.  Why the odd pluralization?  Is 'StaffNames' the correct name?  BTW, there are some strongly-typed versions of `.Include' on the web that can help.  How do you project the data to the right 'shape' for your array?  Can you show that code too?

Comment: They're both variations on the real object names so I just used whatever came to mind.  I just use revQuery.ToArray<DocRevision>(); to return it.  As a bit of background I've been taking a simplistic approach with this as I'm jumping straight from working in .Net 2 and we're a small team with no Linq etc experience.  I'll look into the EDMX, management approval will be required I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow will not let me add an image as I'm too new to the site.

Comment: This is still a problem so we've stopped using EF4/Linq for this operation and had to replace it with DataTables and SQL Stored Procs for now as this solution is my/our comfort zone.  I'm going to keep monitoring this question though in case anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In returning to this problem to try Jack's suggestions I have hit upon a possible answer.  When I had the initial problem I was still in development and was hosting the service and the application on my dev PC.  After working around it I deployed a test version of the WCF service.

When I went to test the changes suggested above my application was still pointing at the test instance of the service (unchanged from last year) which worked!  So the problem appears to be occurring only when you have the service and the calling application on the same machine.  I'll leave the why to smarter people! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the property explicitly rather than using the include method. Can't tell you why the include method isn't working though.

```
    var revQuery = from revs in context.tbl_Document_Revision
                   where (revs.ID == myIDVar)
                   select revs;
    foreach(var rev in revQuery)
    {
    context.LoadProperty(rev, "tbl_staff");
    }
```

Another thing to try would be using a lamda instead of the query syntax and see if that helps.

```
    var revQuery = context.tblDocument_Revision.Include("tbl_staff")
    .Where( tbl => tbl.ID == myIDVar)
```

Comment: Jack, thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately they didn't resolve this.  However they did point out a possible cause which I've added below.